# Validating a russian domain PHP

Tags: php, validation

I have been trying to look for a solution to validate a domain with php, the domain is:

> xn----9sbeid4cgu7b.xn--p1ai

when i paste it into the browser it gets converted to russian characters and the domain is valid, i cannot validate it with

```
$re = '/^(?!\-)(?:[a-zA-Z\d\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,126}(?!\d+)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,63}$/m';
$is_valid = preg_match_all($re, $domain, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) with [FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)?

Comment: That has to be the weirdest valid domainname I've ever seen

Comment: lol.. the weirdest among the weird.. lol.,

Comment: @Martijn Welcome to [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)…!?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Unicode domain name from an IDNA ASCII-compatible format to plain Unicode (encoded in UTF-8) with [idn_to_utf8](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-utf8.php).

Comment: any solution with PHP 5.6?

Comment: I use PHP7 and stil goit this error : Call to undefined function idn_to_utf8

Comment: It has more requirements then just PHP: `(PECL intl >= 1.0.2, PECL idn >= 0.1)`

Comment: @Martijn please explain

Comment: @WasifKhalil you must install intl and idn PECL packages

Comment: im on mac and installed intl "brew install php70-intl" but it still didnt work...can someone tell me how to install idn?